# Double-click selection to select by word in Thunderbird for Linux?

Tags: linux, thunderbird

In Mac OS, if you select text by double-clicking and dragging (sometimes called "click and a half"), the selection advances word by word. In Linux, using Gnome, I am only able to get this behavior in select applications, like Terminal and FireFox. Is there any way to get Thunderbird to have the same functionality/behavior?

Comment: It's doing that for me by default in Ubuntu 9.04. Tested it in both Firefox and Terminal.

Comment: djhowell, please make that an answer to Josh can accept it.  You are of course correct.

Comment: @djhowell, yes, please make that an answer and I will accept it. Looks like this is application specific because Thunderbird doesn't do this.

Comment: @Josh maybe you could just close this as "answered in the comments" or answer it yourself?

Comment: @Cawas: I was waiting for him to post a real answer so I could accept it. Looks like he's not going to. Want a free +15 rep? ;-)

Comment: @Josh not really. ;) I still think you should either close this or answer it yourself. I'm not sure which one is the best practice, tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's doing that for me by default in Ubuntu 9.04. Tested it in both Firefox and Terminal. – djhowell Oct 12 '09 at 18:53

All credit to [djhowell](https://superuser.com/users/8551/djhowell), i'm just after some free/easy points!!1 ;)